# How do I make Varnish purge all variants of a URL?

Tags: varnish

Varnish 2.1: I'm trying to use http PURGE to get Varnish to renew one cached URL.

While testing, I would get results that seemed strange until I read this bit in the documentation: "If there are several variants of the same URL in the cache however, only the matching variant will be purged. To purge a gzip variant of the same page the request would have to look like this:"

So now if I do these two commands:

```
curl -I http://example.com/my-url
curl -X PURGE http://example.com/my-url
```

I get back a 200 Purged response.

And if I do these two:

```
curl -I http://example.com/my-url -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
curl -X PURGE http://example.com/my-url -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
```

I also get a 200 Purged.

Now if I try:

```
curl -I http://example.com/my-url -H "Accept-Encoding: deflate"
```

I get back headers that indicate that the Content-Encoding: is "text/html;charset=utf-8", and it has age in the cache. That seems to indicate that "deflate" isn't being supported by my app, which is probably correct.

The page also has an Age: header indicating that it's being cached.

Now how do I purge that? (Am I asking a moot question?)

All of these attempts return "404 Not in cache":

```
curl -X PURGE http://example.com/my-url -H "Accept-Encoding: deflate"
curl -X PURGE http://example.com/my-url -H "Accept-Encoding: text/html;charset=utf-8"
curl -X PURGE http://example.com/my-url -H "Accept-Encoding: text/html"
```

Is there a magic way to purge all of the variants of a URL?

Comment: Does your VCL have entries for both `vlc_hit` and `vlc_miss`?

Comment: Umm, let me rephrase, pardon me asking an improper question. I meant to ask whether it has _purge_ entries for both hit and miss.

Comment: Yes, and I can see them both executing correctly in the first and second examples. I've seen both Purged and "Not in cache" results from those routines on the PURGE call.

Comment: Out of curiosity.. What would you get if you try `curl -I http://example.com/my-url -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"`, followed by `curl -X PURGE http://example.com/my-url`? I'm not sure why it doesn't work in your example, other than response cached wasn't a page, but from what I understand, just purging a url should purge all instances of it. That being said, my varnish experience is rather non-extensive.

Comment: That test returns "404 not in cache". If I repeat the purge and add -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" it returns "200 Purged." That's pretty much the gist of my problem -- how to purge all variations of a cached page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14960/discussion-between-mojo-and-favoretti)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aha, by applying some google-fu, I stumbled on a forum post, that suggests the following:

```
purge("req.url ~ ^" req.url "$");
```

i.e. using a regexp behind purge, to handle all `Accept-Encoding` headers.

More info here: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/varnish/misc/15124

.. which means you need to modify your VCL though.

Comment: Oh, nicely done sir! I'm going to test that out. Changing the VCL is fine. Will report back.

Comment: Here's a question though ... the example in the link uses a call called "purge()", but my VCL code looks more like the tutorial purge code here: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/purging.html which doesn't have a purge() call, just setting the obj.ttl to 0.

Comment: I meant https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/tutorial/purging.html which covers 2.1, not 3.0

Comment: My ultimate solution includes upgrade to Varnish 3, which was no small feat using Chef with Ubuntu 10

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what u need:

```
acl purge {
        "localhost";
        "192.168.55.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
        # allow PURGE from localhost and 192.168.55...

        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                        error 405 "Not allowed.";
                }
                return (lookup);
        }
}

sub vcl_hit {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}

sub vcl_miss {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}
```